# Convergence in $L^{2}$ implying a convergence $a.e.$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $R: \Omega\times(t_{0}, \infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with $\Omega$ being a domain of $\mathbb{R}^{d} (d\geq 1)$. Prove that

If $R(t)\to 0$ in $L^{2}(\Omega)$ as $t\to \infty,$ then $R(x, t)\to 0 \;a.e.$ in $\Omega\times(t_{0}, \infty)$ as $t\to \infty.$

How could I do this using sequences?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Surely false. Take any sequence $f_n$ which tends to $0$ in $L^{2}$ but not a.e. Take $R(x,t)=f_n(x)$ if $n<t <n+1$ and $0$ if $t \notin (n,n+1)$.